# Why does this JavaScript code conflict alongside other JavaScript plugins?

Tags: php, jquery, html

My code is a website counter (`counter.php`). It works perfectly when run directly, meaning
each time you refresh the page the counter increments starting from `5754`; however, when the `counter.php` is included in another page containing other jQuery plugins, it stops working. The counter is static then; it will show `5754` all the time.

Please help me and clarify where I am going wrong.

This section is where the incrementation (counting of the visitors) takes place:

```
<?php
session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['executed']))
$_SESSION['executed'] = $_SESSION['executed']+ 1;
else
$_SESSION['executed'] = 5754;
?>
```

The page itself, which is self explanatory:

```
<head> 
<script src="counter/js/jquery-1.7.1.j"> type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where the counter leaves:

```
<div class="counter-wrap"> 

    <div class="counter-number">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>

<div>
```

An inline CSS:

```
<style>

.counter-wrap {
    height:18px;
    overflow:hidden;   
}

.counter-number {
    height:198px;
    width:12px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(http://developer.mindtouch.com/@api/deki/files/4548/=counter_ticker_bg.gif);  
    float:left;
}

</style>
```

And now the jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".counter-number").each( function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id','num'+i);    
});

function loadinput() {
    var newval = $("#numgo").val();
    loadticker(newval);
}

function loadticker(ticnum) {
    var fticnum = add_commas(ticnum);
    var numheight=18;
   addticker(fticnum);
    if (ticnum && ticnum != 0) {

        var s = String(fticnum);

        for (i=s.length;i>=0; i--)
        {
            var onum=s.charAt(i);          
            $("#num"+i).attr('value',onum);
        }

        $(".counter-number").each( function() {
            var nval=$(this).attr("value");
            if (!isNaN(nval)) {
                var nheight = Number(nval)*numheight*-1;
                $(this).animate({ top: nheight+'px'}, 1500 );
            }
            if (nval==','){
                $(this).animate({ top: '-180px'}, 1500 );
            }
        });
    }
}

function addticker(newnum) {
    var digitcnt = $(".counter-number").size();
    var nnum = String(newnum).length;
    var digitdiff = Number(nnum - Number(digitcnt));
    if (digitdiff <0) {
        var ltdig = (Number(nnum)-1);
        $(".counter-number:gt(" + ltdig + ")").remove();
    }

    for(i=1;i<=digitdiff;i++) {
        $(".counter-wrap").append('<div class="counter-number" id="num' + (Number(digitcnt+i-1)) + '">&nbsp;</div>');
    }

}

function add_commas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');

    }
    return x1 + x2;

}


</script>

</head>
```

Here is where the function is called:

```
<body onload="loadticker( '<?php echo $_SESSION['executed'];  ?>' ) ">

</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: You sure it's a jQuery problem? How do you add this to another page? it sounds like a cache issue that the browser do not send request anymore

Comment: Please remove any code that doesn't demonstrate the problem you are having. You'll have better success getting a good answer to your question.

Comment: I see lots of potential problems.. First off, are you sure you meant to leave the s off the end of "counter/js/jquery-1.7.1.j". Also (while on that line) are you sure that the line loading jquery will always have the correct path if you leave it relative like that? Also, are you setting the html content (as described) with the counter.php? Could you perhaps be setting the head, body and html tags with the other php files? Also, could you be doing something with the other "plugins" to cause the session cookie to be tampered with?... Just some things to clarify and double check.

Comment: are you sure your script tag (`<script src="counter/js/jquery-1.7.1.j"> type="text/javascript"></script> `) is correct? have you checked for any js related errors in firebug?

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of trouble to do this. Usually this is done by storing page visits in a text file, and then using PHP's get_contents and put_contents, so everytime a page in your site is loaded you get the number in the textfile, increment it by one in a variable, put it back in the text file, and just inlude the variable with the number somewhere in your site? Why would you need a counter that starts at an imaginary number, and only counts pageviews in each session ?

Comment: @ghbaratt Good observation. This is what the code looks like alone: http://www.whatstheproggy.com/counter/counter.php When I include it in the http://www.ug-mart.com/ page (look at the bottom of the page to view the counter) I have to disable the script src or it doesnt work at all. hence the s in counter/js/jquery-1.7.1.j missing. help me understand this...

Comment: @Simon Wang, this is how I added it to this page (ug-mart.com)  <li> VISITOR COUNT: <?php $includeFile = file_get_contents("http://www.whatstheproggy.com/counter/counterCopy.php"); echo $includeFile;?> </li>

Comment: @nicolasides. I do not understand where in the code the error lies, so i thought I would include the entire code.

Comment: Have you tried skipping the body onload part and using the standard document ready to run your function instead. Also, I'm getting the error : http://developer.mindtouch.com/@api/deki/files/4548/=counter_ticker_bg.gif ---- does not exist!

Comment: I think @h4b0 is right, you  jquery script tag looks wrong

Comment: @adeneo I tried using the standard JQuery document ready to run my function but it still results in the same result as in when I use the previous onload. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: Well, there are som issues! Start by adding a check to your PHP to make sure the executed value in your session is actually an integer, just to be sure, then there's the issue of showing the entire page in an iFrame, and then there is the issue of the broken slider. You seem to be using a slider from CodeCanyon that is not working on your site, fix it or remove it! And then, there is the issue of adding just to much crap and plugins, there could be a conflict anywhere in there. And last but not least, why not just make a counter that actually counts visitors, and not just some made up number?

Comment: @adeneo I figured out what the issue was, using onload() or the standard document ready can NEVER work because the the document counterCopy.php never gets loaded by a browser. It took me a while to figure out that including the functionality in counterCopy.php to the index page, and triggering the desired action by using the  onload() function, would give me the desired action. I am aware that this would have worked as well as the standard document ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me that it's a jQuery problem. I would suggest trying to add your PHP code at the top of your code, even before you `<html>` opening tag.

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['executed'])) {
    $_SESSION['executed'] = $_SESSION['executed']+ 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['executed'] = 5754;
}

echo $_SESSION['executed'];

?>
<html>
<head></head>
...
<body onload="loadticker('<?php echo $_SESSION['executed']; ?>')">
</body>
</html>
```